# Xcode compile time very slow after upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, osx-mavericks

I am using Xcode 5. When I had Mountain Lion installed, doing a build after a clean took less than 10 seconds for my project. It was extremely fast.

After upgrading to Mavericks, doing a build after a clean now takes about 2 minutes for my project. It takes almost one second to compile each source file! The source code is exactly the same as the code before the upgrade, so I know that this problem is definitely caused by the Mavericks upgrade.

Running the top command shows about 15 clang processes during build time. Each clang process keeps switching from the "sleeping" and "stuck" state. So I'm wondering if this issue has something to do with race conditions with the multiple clang processes.

So far I have tried rebooting, and reinstalling XCode.

**Edit**

Other Info: I'm using the latest macbook pro with retina display with 16GB of ram. I also have file vault enabled. Will try disabling it to see if it changes performance.

Comment: make sure Spotlight Indexing has finished running...my whole system was crawling until it finished indexing after upgrade to Mavericks. Start in Activity Monitor, and see if xCode is the only process taking up the CPU.

Comment: In particular, if Spotlight indexing is running you'll see processes like "mdworker" and other "md*" processes. (md = metadata) Xcode indexing also makes my project slow to a crawl, but it sounds like your project is pretty small so I'd hope Xcode could index it in a matter of minutes or less.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the spotlight doesn't appear to be the issue. I've just tried rebuilding it and then completely disabling it. Interestingly, the build speed doesn't seem to change at all once it is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem. Turns out it was my virus scanner McAfee. It must have been scanning every source file before letting Xcode compile it. The weird thing is the virus scanner was taking up almost no cpu cycles.

Comment: Is there something specific you did to disable McAfee for your builds but still keep it enabled on your machine?